# Making a custom dash style for GMap.Net.WinForm route stroke

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

I want to make custom path for each route in my GMap.Net.WinForm Project.  How can I do that?

I know there is something like Custom DashStyle. Actually I want to make an arrow from one point to another one.
Is it possible to use it to do that?

```
 route.Stroke = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 3);
 mainRoute.Stroke.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Custom;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [AdjustableArrowCap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.adjustablearrowcap) object to create the EndCap of a dashed line that represents a scalable triangular shape.

The two float values represent the length of the lines that start from the end point of the dash. The `bool` value specifies whether the shape should be filled.

Assign this object to the [CustomEndCap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.customendcap) property of your Pen:

```
var routePen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3) {
    DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash,
    CustomEndCap = new AdjustableArrowCap(3.0f, 3.0f, true)
};

route.Stroke = routePen;
```

Comment: Thank. Excuse me, there is an option for the DashStyle as Custom like: `DashStyle = DashStyle.Custom`. Do you know how may I use that? I've asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77430256/making-a-custom-pen-dashstyle-in-a-winforms-project

Comment: @Javad-M That property allows to generate a custom dash pattern, which sets different values for lines and spaces. It cannot be used to draw other symbols. You could create a Pen that uses a custom Brush, e.g., a TextureBrush, that uses a Bitmap, so you could theoretically draw any symbol. Not simple to get right, since you don't control the rendering of the Pen and the scale of the drawing