# Making a custom Pen DashStyle in a WinForms project

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I want to make a custom DashStyle for the following routePen in my WinForms project. The following pen draws a solid line, there are also some other choices like dot, dash, custom etc. I want to have my custom symbol for the drawn route like star(*) or something else. How may I make that? Maybe the custom choice is what I want, but I don't know how to use that.

```
var routePen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2)
{
     DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid,
     CustomEndCap = new AdjustableArrowCap(6.0f, 6.0f, false),
};
```